# Is it possible to see numbers I typed in previous call?

Tags: calls, call-history

Here's the thing, someone called me today and during the call I pressed a few numbers, then the call ended before I could save them somewhere. Is it possible to find them somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using this [Number Saver App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arnonse.savenum).
App description is as follows:

> Save a number while you're in a phone call, and dial it right after.
>
> Access during call from notification bar, or from app icon
>
> To pull notification bar in the call screen, press HOME first (Android limitation)
>
> The app has two modes for number or note:
>
> - Save it to the clipboard (which later you can 'paste' it wherever you like)
> - Save it in the internal app memory
>
>   On both you can later access the last saved number or note and create a contact, dial or SMS.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: But this works only for calls after you installed the apps, not for past calls ?

Comment: Yes. You just dialed those number, but never saved to clipboard/anything. So it got cleared.